# GRPC load balancing and duplex streaming

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, grpc-c#

We are using a .NET client for GRPC: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet
We are using DuplexStream since many messages can come on the same channel which is initialized first by the client.
How do we achieve Client-based load balancing while communicating with Kubernetes-based GRPC service? Should we create a headless service for GRPC in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

A headless service is necessary if you are using DNS resolution. It's essential for clients to discover pod IPs through DNS.

See this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) for additional info.